# how use object array

Tags: java, listview

Hi guys I am new to java and I am stuck.

I have created a class called song with the code below

```
package musiclibrary;

public class Song {
    private String title;
private String albumArtist;
private String genre;
private double price;
private int duration;

    public Song() {
    }

        public Song(String title, String albumArtist, String genre, double price, int duration) {
        this.title = title;
        this.albumArtist = albumArtist;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.price = price;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAlbumArtist() {
        return albumArtist;
    }

    public void setAlbumArtist(String albumArtist) {
        this.albumArtist = albumArtist;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(int durationSeconds) {
        this.duration = durationSeconds;
    }
}
```

and i have created an object array as shown below

```
     private  ObservableList<Song> songs =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     public  ObservableList<Song> load()
     {
     songs.add(new Song("J. Cole", "Lost Ones", "Hip Hop", 24.66, 3000));
     songs.add(new Song("Erykah Badu", "Time's a wasting", "Neo-Soul", 24.66, 4000));
     songs.add(new Song("Common", "Book of Life", "Hip Hop", 24.66, 2000));
     songs.add(new Song("CommonGround", "dasdsad", "asdsadsad", 24.66, 3000));
     return  songs;
     }
```

Problem is that I don't know how to call the "load" function in a listView in the main method. below is what i have

```
  private ListView<Song> ListView;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

          PlayList pl= new PlayList();
          ListView.setItems(pl.play());



    }
```

Attached is the result. please help!

[image: Result]

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Are you unsatisified with the representation of the songs? If so, you may want to overwrite the [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) method of `Song` (for more details, see [the corresponding Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Seems as though you're displaying the default [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) inherited from `java.lang.Object`. You should override it in `Song` and display the information you want. E.g., let's assume you just want to display the Song's title and artist:

```
@Override
public Sting toString() {
    return title + " by " + albumArtist;
}
```